# Role of these drivers

Tags: drivers

What is the Intel Chipset Driver and Intel Wireless Audio driver? What these two drivers accomplish? 
I was hunting for my Win 7 drivers for a Lenovo PC and found these two listed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel Chipset Driver contains all the drivers needed for your computer to properly user your various components. USB, SATA, etc.. The Intel Wireless Audio Driver is for utilizing WiDi. Which lets you broadcast your video and audio wireless to a compliant device that is usually connected to a TV.